# How to compare a string value to another string value?

Tags: php, google-maps, laravel-5, compare

I have a problem in comparing a string of single word to another string within a sentence or phrase.I want to get the whole string from address if the value $Cebu have match the same word
from the value of $address. My aim is if there is an exact match the return is true else false.
Anyone who can help me is much appreciated.

```
public function address(){

    $Cebu = 'Cebu';

    $lt = '10.2638281';
    $lg = '123.60638549999999';
    $str = $lt.','.$lg;

    $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.trim($lt).','.trim($lg).'&sensor=false';

    $json = @file_get_contents($url);
    $data=json_decode($json);   

    $status = $data->status;
    $address = $data->results[0]->formatted_address;



    //Pinamungahan, Cebu, Philippines


}
```

Comment: So it does not look like you have attempted to solve this yourself. Have you tried anything?

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Yes Sir  I've tried to use  strcmp() but its comparing the whole string.What i want if a word has a matching word from the address,meaning it is true then i'll use the data to display.

Comment: Do you want to know if `Cebu` in located somewhere in `$address` Or do you want to know if `Cebu` is the ONLY thing in `$address` Its not quite clear from your question

Comment: did you try strpos() or stripos()??

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Yes, i want to know if word Cebu is on the located somewhere in $address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can compare using this ...

```
if (strpos($string, $word) === FALSE) {
    // word does NOT exists in string
} else {
    // word DOES exist in string
}
```

Note that strpos() is case sensitive, if you want a case-insensitive search, use stripos() instead.

Comment: if you want strict comparion than you can use ===

Comment: why is the comparison is === FALSE? Meaning to say it's not Found?